# How to ask how much shipping is

Tags: translation

I'd like to ask "how much will shipping be to the uk?" in a polite way

Uk is 英国, shipping is 运费, and to ask how much something is is 多少钱, but I'm not sure how to put them together.

Comment: jukuu 1.  What is the freight charge?
 运费多少钱?

Comment: for added  politeness might put ＂请问＂in front

Answer (score 2):

请问到英国的运费需要多少钱？

"to the UK" should be put in front of "shipping", and the sentence can be translated back to

how much is required for the shipping to the UK?

“请问” is for politeness, and “需要” make it formal.